# update List whenever database table change

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

i have a helper class which contain a list of enumeration value ( values return from database ) which are used in project in many places currently i use a timer to update list my question what is best way to update list whenever there is a change in database ?
( note  : db is oracle )

Comment: can you please be more specific which database are you using as well as edit the tags for the question. this will help you to get more appropriate answer.

Comment: k i update my question

Comment: What have you researched so far? There are tons of results in google for this kind of thing [example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/changenotification/odpnetchg_otn.htm) [example](http://bartwullems.blogspot.ie/2009/10/database-change-notification-in-oracle.html)

Comment: Do you need [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx)?